# How to execute this sql query even if last character is provided or not provided

Tags: sql

It should return same row even if last character is provided or not provided

```
DECLARE @FolderNo VARCHAR(50) = 'T98/11567A'
select * from Cm.Folder WHERE FolderNo LIKE @FolderNo +'_'


DECLARE @FolderNo VARCHAR(50) = 'T98/11567'
select * from Cm.Folder WHERE FolderNo LIKE @FolderNo +'_'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If multiple trailing characters are okay,

```
DECLARE @FolderNo VARCHAR(50) = 'T98/11567A'
select * from Cm.Folder WHERE FolderNo LIKE @FolderNo + '%'
```

or

```
DECLARE @FolderNo VARCHAR(50) = 'T98/11567A'
select * from Cm.Folder WHERE LEFT(FolderNo, LEN(@FolderNo)) = @FolderNo
```

If zero or one trailing character is okay,

```
DECLARE @FolderNo VARCHAR(50) = 'T98/11567A'
select * from Cm.Folder WHERE FolderNo = @FolderNo OR FolderNo LIKE @FolderNo + '_'
```